NodeJS Dependabot alert "ws affected by a DoS when handling a request with many HTTP headers" conflicts: react-scripts, ws and jsdom
I have the following Dependabot alert
Title: ws affected by a DoS when handling a request with many HTTP headers
Desciption: Dependabot cannot update ws to a non-vulnerable version
The latest possible version that can be installed is 7.5.10 because of the following conflicting dependencies:
Conflicting dependencies: react-scripts@5.0.1 requires ws@^7.4.6 via a transitive dependency on jsdom@16.7.0
No patched version available for ws
The earliest fixed version is 8.17.1.
This is my package.json
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "myapp-frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.20",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "html-react-parser": "^5.1.10",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

How can I solve this Dependabot alert? I want to use the latest version for all dependencies.

Migrate off react-scripts.

Jonrshape: Thank you. How can I do this? What is the replacement for react-scripts?

Vite's about the easiest, if you still want a simple SPA - https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2023/Dec/17/js-tdd-vite.html
